# cross platform exclamation point in command line for 7z

Tags: command-line, cross-platform

My script needs to use following command:

```
`{archiver_path}7za a -xr!*.tmp myarchive.7z myfolder`
```

It needs to be run on windows and on linux.

On linux it crashes with "event not found" message, so i modify it to:

```
`{archiver_path}7za a -xr\!*.tmp myarchive.7z myfolder`
```

But it probably wont work this way if i run it on windows system?

And if not, is it possible to somehow make it cross platform?

update:i am trying to find out whether its possible to do it without checking which platform am i on in my scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking this link : http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/90255
then do something like this...

```
if(system="WIN_32")
{
    `{archiver_path}7za a -xr!*.tmp myarchive.7z myfolder`
}
if(system="LINUX")
{
    `{archiver_path}7za a -xr\!*.tmp myarchive.7z myfolder`
}
```

btw, thats not real code.. :P its just an example :D

Comment: yeah i know i could do that, but i was thinking maybe there is some sort of command line trick so that i wouldn't have to.. :]

Comment: the shells that use `!` as a syntax element allow you to either turn off that processing or redefine that element with something else, so that ! doesn't have any effect. It's not certain you'll be able to avail yourself of something like `set no!processing` that will be invisible in windows. I think the above is your best bet in the long run, butusing `if .. elseif ... else .... endif` tests (with final else  clause for the unplanned for case) . Good luck to all.